# Receiving duplicate signals. How to search for the cause?

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a wrote a Django signal in the `__init__.py` of my project. looks like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from paypal.standard.ipn.models import PayPalIPN

def confirm_paypal_payment(sender, **kwargs): 
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    ...
    ...

post_save.connect(confirm_paypal_payment, sender=PayPalIPN, dispatch_uid="confirm_paypal_payment")
```

This signal waits for saves in this model, https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/ipn/models.py

I'm stuck and cannot understand why I continue to receive duplicate signals, I've read the documentation and it said that I should use `dispatch_uid` to prevent this. But even using `dispatch_uid` I continue to receive duplicate signals.

Any ideas on how to find the root cause for this? I'm using Django 1.6.2.

Comment: I removed [tag:django-paypal] because your question is more about signals, it just so happens that you are also using django-paypal, but this would have come up even if you were not :)

Answer (score 1):

Move it out of your `__init__.py` and save it either `signals.py` (a new file that is in your app directory, the same place as `views.py`) or in your `models.py`, which is recommended in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions):

> You can put signal handling and registration code anywhere you like.
>   However, you’ll need to make sure that the module it’s in gets
>   imported early on so that the signal handling gets registered before
>   any signals need to be sent. This makes your app’s `models.py` a good
>   place to put registration of signal handlers.

The `__init__.py` is a very bad place to put code like this, because there is a very good chance it will be executed more than once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Burhan. How the `signals.py` is called? I should import signals somewhere?

Comment: You can import it in your `models.py`, or put the code directly in models.py as recommended by the documentation. See my edit.

Comment: The model is a 3rd party application that resides on `virtualenv`. What is the Best Practices for this use case?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the exact models.py, you can put it in your own models.py, just make sure you import the 3rd party models first.